# Download file in the background rather than in the main UI thread

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

Is there a way to download the file in the background instead of on the main UI thread. Sometimes the download hangs which caused the UI to be unresponsive, so i think having the task done in the background might be able to prevent this issue.

Comment: **You can use External URLs** BY configuring path in tomcat  and use javascript code

Answer (score 4):

Spawn an async thread and use `@Push` + `ui.access()`. See https://youtu.be/ZywjOZYWBuQ